# JavaScript to click a button in asp.net doesn't work in master page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My problem is how to click a button in asp.net using JavaScript

it works perfectly when I'm not using master page but when I put the JavaScript code to master page it doesn't work. What is the problem?

This is the aspx code

```
<button type="button"  id="btnShowPopup" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>
```

This is the codebehind

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
```

This is the JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() {
        $("#btnShowPopup").click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look to the generated HTML, maybe the master page is changing the control ID.

Comment: show your master page

Comment: Is the script and button on same file?

Comment: Are you sure your control is not being made "server side" with the inclusion of `runat="server"`... because that will change it's **rendered** ID as sent with the HTML to the browser when placed within either a `UserControl` or a page with a `MasterPage` setup

Comment: the generated html changes the control id

from btnShowPopup it became ContentPlaceHolder1_btnShowPopup how to solve it? thank you. i tried to search for the solution but i didn't get the correct answer. maybe i don't know the keyword to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling your button by using ClientID assuming your button has `runat="Server"` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() {
        $("#<%= btnShowPopup.ClientID %>").click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried it but it says The name 'btnShowPopup' does not exist in the current context
the i put the javascript in the master page file